# This code from Geeks for Geeks website about BFS

Tags: c++

I want to ask why he considers `list<int> *adj` as an array of adjacency lists. I think this is only a dynamic array but not array of lists? Can someone explain me please?

```
// Program to print BFS traversal from a given 
// source vertex. BFS(int s) traverses vertices  
// reachable from s. 
#include<iostream> 
#include <list> 
  
using namespace std; 
  
// This class represents a directed graph using 
// adjacency list representation 
class Graph 
{ 
    int V;    // No. of vertices 
  
    // Pointer to an array containing adjacency 
    // lists 
    list<int> *adj;    
public: 
    Graph(int V);  // Constructor 
  
    // function to add an edge to graph 
    void addEdge(int v, int w);  
  
    // prints BFS traversal from a given source s 
    void BFS(int s);   
}; 
  
Graph::Graph(int V) 
{ 
    this->V = V; 
    adj = new list<int>[V]; 
} 
  
void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w) 
{ 
    adj[v].push_back(w); // Add w to v’s list. 
}
```

Comment: *This code from Geeks for Geeks website about BFS* -- Code from a place that has a history of bad code examples.  `list<int> *adj;` -- That is not an array, that is a pointer.  There is no array there.  This: `std::vector<std::list<int>> adj;` is a dynamic array of `std::list<int>`.  Then instead of `new[]`, `Graph::Graph(int V):adj(V) {}`.  You wouldn't even need the `V` member anymore.

Comment: `new list<int>[V]` effectively creates a "array" of `V` elements in memory, where each element is a `list<int>` object. The assignment to `adj` makes `adj` point to the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to ask why he considers `list<int> *adj;` is an array of adjacency
> lists ....

It isn't an array, it is a pointer to a `list<int>`.  Pointers are not arrays.

> I think this is only a dynamic array but not array of lists ?

It's not a dynamic array.

What the author is trying to say, but very clumsily, is that the pointer will eventually point to an area in memory that will contain a contiguous buffer of `std::list<int>` objects, thus the usage of the term "dynamic array".

In the example, the buffer is created with the line:

`adj = new list<int>[V];`

in the `Graph` constructor.  This creates `V` `std::list<int>` objects in contiguous memory, and `adj` will point to the first one in the list.

---

The issue with the code is that the author could have used a better tool for the job: `std::vector<std::list<int>>`.

Usage of `std::vector` will

1. Get rid of the usage of raw pointers.
2. Make dynamic arrays much easier to handle.
3. Makes the code you write smaller and less error prone.
4. Removing the need for `new[]` and `delete[]`

Right now, that `Graph` class has memory leaks.  If you use it anywhere except in a toy program, it quickly becomes unusable until proper copy semantics are introduced by writing a user-defined copy constructor, user-defined assignment operator, and destructor.

Here is a rewrite of the `Graph` class:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <list> 
#include <vector>

class Graph 
{ 
   std::vector<std::list<int>> adj;    

public: 
    Graph(int V); 
    void addEdge(int v, int w);  
    void BFS(int s);   
}; 
  
Graph::Graph(int V) : adj(V) {}
 
void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w) 
{ 
    adj[v].push_back(w); 
    // and if you want to add some debugging for boundary conditions, 
    // replace previous line with
    // adj.at(v).push_back(w);
}
```

That entire class can be used safely in any context.  Note there is no need for the `V` member variable, as `adj.size()` knows what `V` is.